# return a list for the given number

Tags: python, arraylist

I know how assign items to empty array using append :

```
matri=[]
def matr_meth(n):
 
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri.append(i)
  return matri  

print(matr_meth(6))
```

but here I saw another way that I don't get how can we assign the index to the name of array matri +=[i] , I would get it if matri[i] =i+1 for exaple cuz alawys array is compared to index like c and c++ maybe , second in the new method it won't work if I define the matri=[] before the method same as I did in the append way:

```
def matr_meth(n):
  matri=[]
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri +=[i]
  return matri  

print(matr_meth(6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stumbled upon two related but distinct questions here. Let's start with the first one. `[i]`, on its own, is not an array subscript operator. It's a list with one element in it. So

```
matri += [i]
```

is really just

```
matri = matri + [i]
```

or, more verbosely,

```
my_temporary_list = [i]
matri = matri + my_temporary_list
```

and `+` is defined on lists to be concatenation. So it's just a fancier way of putting the two lists together. It's not really useful in this example (I would definitely use `.append` if I only had one element to append), but if you have a whole list (whose length might be greater than one), it's quicker to append it in one go. For instance, your `for` loop

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
  matri +=[i]
```

can actually be written as

```
matri += range(1, n + 1)
```

`+=` on `list` can take any iterable, such as `range`, as an argument.

Now for your second question.

```
def matr_meth(n):
  matri=[]
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri += [i]
  return matri
```

Here, `matri` is a local variable in `matr_meth`.

```
matri=[]
def matr_meth(n):
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri.append(i)
  return matri
```

Here, `matri` is a global variable, plain and simple. Where it gets nebulous is

```
matri=[]
def matr_meth(n):
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri += [i]
  return matri
```

Now we're assigning to `matri` both inside and outside of the function (remember, `+=` is just a shortcut for `=` and `+` together). So Python could reasonably assume that `matri` is a global variable, or it could reasonably assume that you meant to make a new local variable inside the function. To avoid action-at-a-distance errors, Python makes the conservative choice to assume you meant `matri` to be a new local variable. Since you intended the opposite in this case, just use the `global` keyword.

```
matri=[]
def matr_meth(n):
  global matri
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri += [i]
  return matri
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def matr_meth(n):
  matri=[]
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri += [i]
  return matri
```

You initialized `matri=[]` as an empty list, which is a list. `[i]` is also a list. If you apply the `+` operator between two lists, it is essentially appending the second list to the first list.

In the for loop you are appending every `[i]` to `matri`. `matri` keeps changing in the for loop. You can view it by using the print function.

```
def matr_meth(n):
  matri=[]
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    matri += [i] 
    print('At the '+str(i)+'-th iteration, matri is: ' )
    print(matri)      
  return matri  


matr_meth(6)
```

Output:

```
At the 1-th iteration, matri is: 
[1]
At the 2-th iteration, matri is: 
[1, 2]
At the 3-th iteration, matri is: 
[1, 2, 3]
At the 4-th iteration, matri is: 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
At the 5-th iteration, matri is: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
At the 6-th iteration, matri is: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```